# How to provide only create IAM user access for a certain user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

How to provide only create + view IAM user access policy for a certain IAM user instead of providing IAMFullAccess permission, while creating IAM users via Terraform script

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to achieve. Your post is not very informative.

Comment: I am using terraform to create an IAM user with certain credentials and I just want the deployer to have only limited permissions to create an IAM user and not IAMFullAccess permission which seems to provide everything

Comment: I think you should look at [permission boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) which allow your developer to create any permissions within the boundaries.